# how to redirect apache port 80 to jetty port 8080?

Tags: apache, maven, redirect, jetty, port

I have a VPS server with a domain example.com, with apache2 listening port 80

Then, I have a web app in jetty server (running with mvn jetty:run), listening in port 8080

When I type example.com in a browser, I get a apache example page "it works!"
If I write example.com:8080 I get my webapp

Question is simple, how can I redirect for when I write example.com so that I get to my webapp?

I cant change port jetty to 80, its error.
 command "sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080" does not anything effect

So, how can i make apache redirect 80 to 8080? in sites-enabled/default-000?

Please explain carefully, I'm a newbie with systems ;(

Thank you

EDIT

I solved it with this:

http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/how-to-port-forward-apaches-80-to.html#.VImt1XvyOPU

But last line:

RewriteRule ^/(.*) ......:8080/0,81 € [P,L]

Makes error at restart apache
I deleted it and works fine. Any problem with this? What is RewriteRule?

Comment: Use a reverse proxy for this. Not really any point in changing kernel routing, and you get extra bells and whistles and more flexibility if you do this stuff at layer 7

Answer (score 0):

Using IPTABLES is one possible solution. I don't know much about IPTABLES - but there are a lot of tutorials out there, like this one: http://proghowto.com/iptables-redirect-port-80-to-port-8080

I don't know if that works if you have a running daemon (apache) on the destination port.

The other solution is to use a proxy module in apache to pass requests through to your webapp. On Linux only root users are allowed to use ports below 1000. On Windows you should be able to simply change the port in the jetty configuration.

There are two tutorials I often use, they apply to apache and tomcat but that makes no difference for the apache side:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+virtual+hosts+and+mod_proxy
- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Integrating+Stash+with+Apache+HTTP+Server

This is quite a common setup. Also there is almost no performance impact due to the proxying. Not that a user would notice anything.